# Question regarding Fubini's theorem and a piecewise function

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, proof-writing

Specifically, the question is:

> Consider the function $f:[0,1]\times[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by
>   $$f(x,y)=\Bigg\{\begin{array}{cc}
> y^{-2}&0<x<y<1,\\
> -x^{-2}&0<y<x<1,\\
> 0&otherwise.
> \end{array}$$
>   Show by direct computation that
>   $$\int_0^1\left(\int_0^1f(x,y)dx\right)dy\neq\int_0^1\left(\int_0^1f(x,y)dy\right)dx.$$
>   Why does this not contradict the Fubini's Theorem?

The first thing I need clarification on is how to evaluate these integrals.

Fubini's theorem has many hypotheses. If, for example, we were working with a non-continuous, non-measurable, or non-integrable function, then it wouldn't apply. I need assistance identifying the hypothesis that isn't met.

$\textit{Edit:}$ I removed my incorrect thoughts on this problem to reduce clutter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f$ is defined by 1/monomials. This should hint to you that 0 is not nice, and you should be able to easily show $f$ is not continuous at 0. Here's a graph of $f$ that clearly shows an issue at $0$,

[image]
and a graph of $|f|$,
[image]

Fubini holds for discontinuous functions as well as long as they are Lebesgue integrable, but you should also be able to show that this function is not.

To compute the iterated integral, you should compute the inner integral first. I'll do one in full:

$$LHS = \int_0^1 \left( \int_0^yy^{-2} dx - \int_y^1 x^{-2} dx\right) dy \\= \int_0^1 y^{-1} + \left.x^{-1}\right|_y^1 dy = \int_0^1 y^{-1} + 1 - y^{-1} dy = \int_0^1 dy = 1$$

For $RHS$, you should get $-1$.

Comment: I just edited the post to fix my blunder on the integrals

Comment: @Atsina yes, but you still tried to evaluate $x^{-1}$ at 0

Comment: Right, wow, that was rough.

Comment: @Atsina we all make mistakes, better here than an exam. :) Is the above clear on how to evaluate the LHS integral?

Comment: I'm currently parsing through it. You get the same result as the above answer, but with different intermediary steps, so I'm confirming that I believe both solutions.

Comment: @Atsina I forgot a minus sign in my graph earlier. Also, our steps happen to be exactly the same, we just wrote it differently.

Comment: Okay, I follow the integral computations. That is exactly the clarification I needed. In terms of showing that this does not violate Fubini's theorem, is it necessary to show that it isn't Lebesgue integrable? Although I do have some knowledge of measure theory, this is in preparation for an exam that doesn't assume that level of knowledge.

Comment: @Atsina You should keep in mind the precise statement of your Fubini and show how one assumption isn't satisfied. Eg. it is enough to note the discontinuity at 0 to show that you cannot apply Fubini for continuous functions, if that is all you are allowed in the exam.

Answer (score 1):

For the left-hand-side: Fix some $y\in (0, 1)$. We have
\begin{align*} 
\int_0^1 f(x,y) dx 
&= \int_0^y f(x,y) dx + \int_y^1 f(x,y) dx \\
&= y^{-2}x|_{x=0}^{x=y} + x^{-1} |_{x=y}^{x=1} \\
&= y^{-1} + (1 - y^{-1}) \\
&= 1.
\end{align*}
That is
\begin{align*} 
\int_0^1 \left(\int_0^1 f(x,y) dx \right) dy 
= y|_{0}^1 = 1.
\end{align*}

You might want to recompute the right-hand-side yourself. Also, you might want to reconsider that $f$ is integrable.